# Automatically add Android SDK to PATH

Tags: android, linux, android-sdk-manager

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.  When using the `sdkmanager` CLI, I install the `platform-tools` by running the following command:

```
sudo sdkmanager platform-tools
```

and they are installed in the `$ANDROID_SDK_ROOT/platform-tools` directory.  Good.  However, the new tools, such as `adb`, aren't added to the `$PATH`, and so I can't actually run them unless I type the full path or manually add them.  How can I get `sdkmanager` to automatically add them to the execution search path?

Comment: You can update your `$PATH` variable in .bashrc file, to include the path to the `sdkmanager`.

Comment: I did this, but my question was how do I add new tools automatically?  When I install platform-tools (which includes adb), how can I then be immediately able to run adb from anywhere without manually entering the full path to it?